# How do I run Armory Testnet on Win7 x64 using Bitcoin Core 0.9.3 using remote datadir?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, testnet, windows, armory

Trying to use the testnet which I have no problems with using Bitcoin Core 0.9.3 with command:
`Bitcoin-qt.exe -testnet -datadir=f:\data\bitcoincore`

But running Armory using the Testnet icon attempts to connect to the testnet and crashes Bitcoind.exe

I'm on x64 architecture and believe the problem lies in Armory not finding my remote datadir. Obviously there's the `testnet3` directory inside `f:\data\bitcoincore` ie `f:\data\bitcoincore\testnet3`

I should add I've made a junction point with mklink for `%appdata%\bitcoin` to `f:\data\bitcoincore`

Is anyone aware of either the correct flags passed to Bitcoin Core in the settings of Armory, or the Armory flags, or both, which allow me to run Armory on testnet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question for those interested in the solution:

- Armory and Bitcoin-QT use confusing switches; Armory going for the `--flag` while the latter uses the `-flag`
- A remote Blockchain directory is identified using `--Satoshi-datadir=` while `-datadir=` is used with Bitcoin-QT
- Ensuring the Bitcoin.conf file is correct is the main issue. Correct values required are: listen=1, allowip=127.1.1.1